# Batch file Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/aionemu/c

Tags: multithreading, file, batch-file, exception, program-entry-point

I'm trying to run a batch file, i don't have ecplise or softwares which helps me with java as I've seen around the web
I'm not a genious on java methods so please be kind with me ahah

I get this error

```
Starting Aion German Login Server.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/aionemu/c
ommons/services/cron/RunnableRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at com.aionemu.loginserver.LoginServer.main(LoginServer.java:116)

Login Server Terminated Abnormaly, Please Verify Your Files.


Login Server Terminated.
```

So as i can see with other questions posted I need Java 8 to run this ...

BUT as soon as i try to install my Java 8 i get this error :

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFAow.png)

HELP =(!!

Comment: This is not related to batch scripting. From the exception I can conclude the Aion server you want to log in does not support the client jar you have.

Comment: Your JRE installation is too old to run the JAR you are trying to run.  See linked Q&A for the explanation and solutions.

Comment: Please, do not add futher problems to the question post which has already been resolved. Instead, fill another question post. But before that, try to google for existed solutions.